# Backbone.js + Rails + IE routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, backbone.js, history

In my rails app, I have two layouts/controllers for different actions.

Eseentially, I match the root `/` to gateway#index, along with a few other pages such as `/login` and `/register`

The actual app once logged has its own sets of URLs, such as `/dashboard` `/dashboard/action` `/explore` etc.

Because of the pushstate with IE, the url changes to `/#dashboard` and loads the layout/JS for the gateway pages.

My rails controller for root has the following code, which is resulting in an endless loop in all versions of IE

```
if @current_user
  redirect_to '/dashboard/lists'
end
```

The following is the Backbone history initializer (coffeescript):

```
Backbone.history.start 
  pushState: true
  root: '/dashboard/'
```

Even with this setting, the application renders the gateway layout/JS not the application, and keeps the faulty URL the same (not setting the root to /dashboard).

How can I have IE load the application layout/JS/CSS while still having a different layout for the root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was setting the root to an invalid route. I ended up doing the following:

```
Backbone.history.start 
  pushState: true
  root: '/app/'
```

And creating a route to a controller that used the application template.

Answer (score 1):

From the Backbone website:

> For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include json2.js, and either jQuery.

So have you included `json2.js`?